# How to retrieve this particular array of dictionary [[String: Any]] in the tableView cellforrow section to a label SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

Hi I have following Array of dictionary that retrieved to product ARRAY

```
var productArray = [[String: Any]]()
    [["pk": 1711, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 1712, "quantity": 0], ["quantity": 1, "pk": 1713], ["pk": 1715, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 1716, "quantity": 0], ["quantity": 1, "pk": 1718]]
```

I want to display the "quantity" to a label in cellForRow delegate method. I searched but I couldn't find a working solution that related to my scenario. please help with a simple code snippet as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let product = productArray[indexPath.row]
let quantity = (product["quantity"] as? Int) ?? 0    // default to 0

cell.label.text = "\(quantity)"
```

Answer (score 0):

It will help you to assign productArray to `cellForRowAt indexPath` :

```
 var products = [[String: Any]]()


override func viewDidLoad() {

     super.viewDidLoad()
     
     self.products = [["pk": 1711, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 1712, "quantity": 0], ["quantity": 1, "pk": 1713], ["pk": 1715, "quantity": 0], ["pk": 1716, "quantity": 0], ["quantity": 1, "pk": 1718]]
        
  }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

         guard let quantity = products[indexPath.row]["quantity"] else{
                 return cell
          }

         cell.textLabel?.text = "\(quantity)"

    return cell

}
```

Here we safely assigned quantity value. It will won't crash.